# Fade effect analog RGB strip and NodeMCU

Tags: programming, esp8266, wifi, nodemcu, rgb-led

I have an analog or dumb RGB strip that I control with HTTP commands. I want to be able to make the strip fade between different colours when I call `http://XX.X.X.XXX/fade`. I want it to do this infinitely until another colour is set or it turns on or off. I have tried doing this with a while loop but I can no longer change the state of the light from fading. Does anyone know how to do this? I'll link my code below.

```
//NodeMCU RGB-Controller for Homebridge & HomeKit (Siri)

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

#define redPin 13 //D7 - Red channel
#define grnPin 12 //D6 - Green channel
#define bluPin 14 //D5 - Blue channel

#define max(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))

WiFiServer server(80); //Set server port

String readString;           //String to hold incoming request
String hexString = "FFFFFF"; //Define inititial color here (hex value), 080100 would be a calm warmtone i.e.

int state;

bool fading;

int r;
int g;
int b;

float R;
float G;
float B;

int x;
int V;

///// WiFi SETTINGS - Replace with your values /////////////////
const char* ssid = "SSID";
const char* password = "PASSWORD";
IPAddress ip(XX,X,X,XXX);      // set a fixed IP for the NodeMCU
IPAddress gateway(XX.X.X.X);  // Your router IP
IPAddress subnet(XXX.XXX.XXX.X); // Subnet mask
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void WiFiStart() {
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet); //Set a fixed IP. You can comment this out and set it in your router instead.
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(100);
    Serial.print("_");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Done");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("");

  server.begin();                   
}

void allOff() {
  state = 0;
  for (float fade = 1.0; fade >= 0.0; fade -= 0.01) {
    analogWrite(redPin, map((r * fade), 0, 255, 0, 1023));
    analogWrite(grnPin, map((g * fade), 0, 255, 0, 1023));
    analogWrite(bluPin, map((b * fade), 0, 255, 0, 1023));
    delay(2);
  }
  // Set r/g/b to 0 so fade in is possible
  r = 0;
  b = 0;
  g = 0;
}

//Write requested hex-color to the pins
void setHex() {
  const float STEPS = 100; // Change number of steps while fading (lower is faster)
  // Save old values of r/g/b
  byte oldR = r;
  byte oldG = g;
  byte oldB = b;
  long number = (long) strtol( &hexString[0], NULL, 16);
  r = number >> 16;
  g = number >> 8 & 0xFF;
  b = number & 0xFF;
  float deltaR = (r - oldR) / STEPS;
  float deltaG = (g - oldG) / STEPS;
  float deltaB = (b - oldB) / STEPS;
  // Fade to new colour
  for (float f = 0; f < STEPS; f++) {
    analogWrite(redPin, map((oldR + (deltaR * f)), 0, 255, 0, 1023));
    analogWrite(grnPin, map((oldG + (deltaG * f)), 0, 255, 0, 1023));
    analogWrite(bluPin, map((oldB + (deltaB * f)), 0, 255, 0, 1023));
    delay(2);
  }
  state = 1;
}

//Compute current brightness value
void getV() {
  R = roundf(r/2.55);  //was (r/10.23);
  G = roundf(g/2.55);  //was (g/10.23);
  B = roundf(b/2.55);  //was (b/10.23);
  x = max(R,G);
  V = max(x, B);
}

//For serial debugging only
void showValues() {
  Serial.print("Status on/off: ");
  Serial.println(state);
  Serial.print("RGB color: ");
  Serial.print(r);
  Serial.print(".");
  Serial.print(g);
  Serial.print(".");
  Serial.println(b);
  Serial.print("Hex color: ");
  Serial.println(hexString);
  getV();
  Serial.print("Brightness: ");
  Serial.println(V);
  Serial.println("");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1);
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(grnPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluPin, OUTPUT);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFiStart();
  setHex();
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();

  if (!client) {
    return;
  }

  while(client.connected() && !client.available()) {
    delay(1);
  }

  //Respond on certain Homebridge HTTP requests
  if (client) {
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        if (readString.length() < 100) {
          readString += c;
        } 
        if (c == '\n') {
          Serial.print("Request: ");
          Serial.println(readString);

          //Send reponse
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); 
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println();

          //On
          if(readString.indexOf("on") >0) {
            setHex();
            showValues();
            fading = false;
          }

          //Off
          if(readString.indexOf("off") >0) {
            allOff();
            showValues();
            fading = false;
          }

          //Fade
          if(readString.indexOf("fade") >0) {
            fade();
            fading = true;
          }

          //Set color
          if(readString.indexOf("set") >0) {
            hexString = "";
            hexString = (readString.substring(9,15));
            setHex();
            showValues();
            fading = false;
          }

          //Status on/off
          if(readString.indexOf("status") >0) {
          client.println(state);
          }

          //Status color (hex)
          if(readString.indexOf("color") >0) {
          client.println(hexString);
          }

          //Status brightness (%)
          if(readString.indexOf("bright") >0) {
          getV();
          client.println(V);
          }

          delay(1);
          client.stop();
          readString="";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void fade() {
  while(fading == true){
    hexString = "000000";
    setHex();
    hexString = "FFFFFF";
    setHex();
    hexString = "FF0000";
    setHex();
    hexString = "008000";
    setHex();
    hexString = "0000FF";
    setHex();
    hexString = "FFFF00";
    setHex();
    hexString = "1E1E1E";
    setHex();
   }
 }
```

Comment: 1. get rid of the `client.read()` malarky using server.on() to handle your API outside of loop(). 2. move your setHex code to loop, and make enough of the control variables globals so that it performs as expected. 3. have your API modify the control variables, like step increment (which can be zero to pause/halt), current colors, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `fading` cannot ever change, once you are in that `while` loop, since your code doesn't do it and you don't use interrupts either (And I don't know, if the library is supporting this). So the Arduino is stuck forever in this loop and will not respond to any interactions but resetting.

There are basically there are 2 different options for you (not counting the usage of a hypothetical interrupt capability of the Wifi library, as I don't know enough about the library):

1. **Adding Wifi code to the `while` loop:** You can just add code, that watches the Wifi interface into the `while` loop and set the `fading` variable correspondingly. This is the easiest to program option.
2. Rewrite your code (especially the `fade()` function) to be non-blocking, which means it will not block the execution of other code, but will only do something, when it is time to do so, and otherwise return from the function. You can achieve this by using the `millis()` function, which returns the milliseconds since the last startup/reset to use as a time source. Refer to the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example of the Arduino IDE. Also you can google for `millis()`; there are a ton of tutorials out there. When writing non-blocking code you might also want to implement a Finite State Machine (FSM). It's simpler as it sounds. You basically define a simple variable, which sets your current state (for example the states `fading`, `off`, `specific_color`, ...). In your `loop()` function you make a `switch(state_variable){ case` statement, where you insert code for every state in it's own `case`. Outside of the `switch` statement you can then check the Wifi interface and set the state variable correspondingly. If everything is written non-blocking it should work like a charm.

Comment: Thank you. It worked when I made a switch case in the loop then made a new function called `handleWifi()` to handle the wifi code.